# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, sql

Intento sacar un dato de una base de datos, pero no consigo que me muestre únicamente el String.
¿En qué estoy fallando?

Gracias,

```
@app.route('/recover', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def recover():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        usuario = request.form.get('usuariorec')
        sql = sqlite3.connect("BD")
        cursor = sql.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select email from usuarios where nombreUsuario=?", (usuario,))
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        print (row)
        ...
```

```
Output
>('account@mail.com',)
```

Necesito que salga así:

```
account@mail.com
```

Si intento con print(row[0]) me indica esto:

```
    print (row[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que `fetchone` retorna `None` si la consulta no retorna nada o si el iterador del cursor está agotado. En tal caso el indizado se intenta hacer sobre `None` y tienes el error mostrado. Deberías hacer algo como:

```
row = cursor.fetchone()
if row is not None:
    row = row[0]
print(row)
```

ó en Python >= 3.8 también:

```
if (row:= cursor.fetchone()) is not None:
    row = row[0]
print(row)
```

Comment: perfecto!! La primera opción que me has dado es la que ha funcionado!! Mil gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar con `print(list(row)[0])`, esto convertira el objeto en una lista y podras acceder al elemento 0 lo que te regresara el string

Comment: lo mismo, me pone:

print (list(row)[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable