# error al conectar python con mySQL

Tags: mysql, python, tkinter, pymysql

hola estoy haciendo un programa en tkinter que esta conectado con mySQL, el error esque cuando ejecute el programa  me salio este error:

runfile('C:/Users/User/Desktop/programa1/programa_empleados.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/Desktop/programa1')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\programa1\programa_empleados.py", line 31, in 
cursor.execute(SQL1)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 163, in execute
result = self._query(query)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 321, in _query
conn.query(q)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 505, in query
self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 724, in _read_query_result
result.read()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1069, in read
first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 676, in _read_packet
packet.raise_for_error()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py", line 223, in raise_for_error
err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
raise errorclass(errno, errval)

OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")

se que me quiere decir que El recuento de columnas no coincide con el recuento de valores en la fila 1 pero a pesar de que se de cervidores no se cual es el error. si alguien save como ayudarme lo agradeceria mucho

aqui mi codigo:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import pymysql
import os


ventana = Tk()

ventana.title("softnum_empleados")

ventana.geometry('900x800')

sernMYSQL = pymysql.connect(
    
    host="sensurado",
    user="sensurado",
    password="sensurado",
    db="sensurado"
    
    )
cursor=sernMYSQL.cursor()


ventana2=Toplevel()
ventana2.geometry('900x800')
etiqueta1=Label(ventana2, text="nombre de usuario")
etiqueta1.place(x=100, y=96)
Rnombre=Entry(ventana2, width=60)
Rnombre.place(x=300, y=100)
SQL1="insert into main_info(andy_handsome,nombre) values ('{}')".format(Rnombre)
cursor.execute(SQL1)

etiqueta2=Label(ventana2, text="apellido de usuario, opcional")
etiqueta2.place(x=100, y=140)
Rapellido=Entry(ventana2, width=60)
Rapellido.place(x=300, y=137)
etiqueta3=Label(ventana2, text="ubicacion local comercial")
etiqueta3.place(x=100, y=170)
Rubicacion_local=Entry(ventana2, width=60)
Rubicacion_local.place(x=300, y=167)
etiqueta4=Label(ventana2, text="email")
etiqueta4.place(x=100, y=193)
Remail=Entry(ventana2, width=60)
Remail.place(x=300, y=196)

def registracion():
    pass

tad_control=ttk.Notebook(ventana)
tad_control.pack()
tad_control.grid(column=0, row=1)
tad1=ttk.Frame(tad_control)
tad2=ttk.Frame(tad_control)
tad3=ttk.Frame(tad_control)

tad_control.add(tad1, text="ventas 1")
tad_control.add(tad2, text="ventas 2")
tad_control.add(tad3, text="compras")

boton1=Button(tad1, text="VENTAS", width=19, height=6, bg="yellow")
boton1.place(x=200, y=400)
boton1.pack()

boton2=Button(tad1, text="DEVOLUCIONES", width=19, height=6, bg="yellow")
boton2.place(x=500, y=400)
boton2.pack()


boton3=Button(tad2, text="SEGUNDAS VENTAS", width=19, height=6, bg="yellow")
boton3.place(x=200, y=400)
boton3.pack() 

boton4=Button(tad3, text="COMPRAS", width=19, height=6, bg="yellow")
boton4.place(x=200, y=400)
boton4.pack()           
ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que crees un nuevo script y empieces hacer las consultas ahí primero(mas que nada para verificar si esta todo okey con tu base de datos, después puedes agregar tu base de datos al script principal), también como buena practica deberías meter la conexión y la consulta en diferentes funciones como en el siguiente código.

```
# conexion

def baseDeDatos():
    db = pymysql.connect(
        host = "localhost",
        user = "usuario",
        passwd = "contraseña",
        database =  "basededatos"
    )

    return db # retornamos la base de datos
```

Primera consulta un simple select.

```
def consulta_select():
    db = baseDeDatos() # nos conectamos a la db
    cursor = db.cursor() # creamos el cursor

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tabla") # ejecutamos la consulta

    datos = cursor.fetchone() # obtenemos todos los datos de la tabla

    db.close() # cerramos la db

    return datos # retornamos los datos

print(consulta_select())
```

también te recomiendo bastante esta pagina [mysql python w3](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp) aquí encontraras mucha información útil.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu solucion pero pregunta: es normal que el resulado se None. porque asi fue el resultado

Comment: @jajjajaj si es raro, debería devolverte una tupla con todos los datos de tu tabla, en el caso que tu base de datos este vacío debería devolverte una tupla vacía.

Comment: @jajjajaj esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/352451/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-subscriptable) quizás te sirva.